# How can assigning an array formula values which referred with a Name, to the List Data-Validation?

Tags: excel, list, validation, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have write below array formula:

```
=INDEX(Table1[Column2],SMALL(IF(Sheet1!G6=Table1[Column1],ROW(Table1[Column1])-ROW(Table1[[#Headers],[Column1]])),ROW($A:$A)))
```

According this **picture1**:

[image: ![![Array formula Picture]

Note that selected range contains above array formula.

**I need** define that array formula returned values in the list form of data validation for `Column2` of right table.

### What I had tried:

I defined a `Name`, because responsively `Sheet1!G6` reference part of above formula have change in `Column2` cells for its appropriated `Column1` cell. (in right table), according to below **picture2**:

[image: ![![![Defining Named Range]

Then set `Column2` of right table's data validation, (**picture3** below):

[image: ![Define list form of Data validation]

### The problem is

But in result, validation list only contains first result of array formula! as **picture4** below:

[image: ![Data validation result list]

### Question

How can define an array formula *valued* results set to a `Name` (Picture 2 above) and use in `List` Data Validation (picture 3 above) for a `Column` of table **?** (Picture 4 above)

> ### My concepts are:
>
> - There where a `array form formula` as shown above. (On the paper and
>     not in a worksheets range, yet)
> - This array formula is corresponding to a set -collection- of (potentially returned) results.
> - I want use above set in the `Data-Validaton List` for a special Table column.
> - Not using helper things (as Sheet, Column, Pivot-table and Etc...)
> - Using (1)- `Name` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>), (2)- the array formula (for generating **valid** results collection), and (3)- `Data-Validation List` (to check is entered value in above special Table column is valid or not valid; and let entering only valid data in that special column))

Comment: I'm not sure Excel can do this the way you are intending. I don't think you can't store an array in a single cell like that. Maybe a PivotTable is a better approach to what you are doing?

Comment: I want create dependent filtered list. And I want do this quietly, without creating helper sheet, helper column or a pivot table. simple way if possible. What is array form formula? I want store array formula in a `Name` as shown above and assign it's results set to a data validation list to cells I want to be filtered.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you don't want to use a helper column or sheet. But saying:

- A Table and an array formula can't coexist.
- Data validation source can't be a complex formula of any kind, but you can use Indirect to a named range or address (but only if its a continuous region, not multiple areas) on the source formula if you want.
- An array is never returned as a whole result in array formula, each cell used on as target destiny of the calculation is an item of the returned array.

So what I would do, return the array formula in a region let's Say A1, and a counter to the number of items in your array result that are valid using another cell B1. Use a cell C1 to determine the address of the list that you want to use. Then use `=INDIRECT(C1)` in the source of your validation.

You can hide other sheet so another use can't see it, and if you hide it by macro you can set it to very hidden and it's not possible to make it visible from the workbook directly. You might also create a named range to the C1 cell in my example so the end user can't see where this source on validation is from.

Comment: How can determine the address of the list I want to use? (In `C1` cell, you told).

Comment: I sent you the e-mail. If you set the beginning of the list in A1 and the size of the array in B1 then the formula to address is `="$A$1:" & ADDRESS(B1,1,1,1)`.

Comment: Unfortunately not work. Please pay attention the approach I was shown in **Picture 2**. In this case that  you suggest, the `A1` list will static, thus I need that list dependent to `G6` in formula shown in **picture1**. In this question we try to produce a dependent validation list, form `Table2[Column1]`. My problem was shown in **picture 4**. The create `Name` approach (**Picture2**) will made the formula related with dynamically change `G6` reference in main formula. But when using in validation list, as shown in **Picture4** only first value will generated.

Comment: I want define an array formula values which referred with a `Name`(Ctrl + F3); to the data validation list.

Comment: It will work, all you gotta do is use the formula that retrieve the valid items in some columns, one for each filtered answer, then you can validate on a range for each cell based on this.

Comment: I need validate cells entered value are in `Table2[Column2]`. And this Table rows are in expend for each day. In above approach you said, I need helper Column for each appropriated cell in each line? I need validate all cells of that column. Is it possible for us to define our `ValidItems` name values to the data-validation list for special cells?